# Condition on p for convergence of $\sum{\frac{1}{n(\log(n))^p}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

For what values of $p$ is the series $\sum{\frac{1}{n(\log(n))^p}}$ divergent and for what values it is convergent?

Comment: Divergent for $p\le 1$, convergent for $p\gt 1$. The Integral Test will work nicely.  So will the likely less familiar Cauchy Condensation Test.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *Bertrand's series*. It converges for any real exponent $p>1$, and diverges for $p\le 1$.
It trivially diverges if $p\le 0$. If $0<p\le 1$, it is enough to prove it diverges for $p=1$. 
As the function $\dfrac1{x\ln x}$ is continuous, decreasing for $x>\dfrac1e$, we may apply Cauchy's integral test:
$$\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{x\ln x}=\ln\ln x\biggr\rvert_2^{+\infty}\enspace\text{diverges,}$$
hence the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n\ln n}\;$ diverges.